# Getting data from wx.ListCtrl after an edit

Tags: python, wxpython

If I create a wx.ListCtrl and use a mixin making me able to edit it, how do I get the data from the cell that got changed? So far I have the code below. When I try to print it/save it in a variable it's empty.

```
def __init__(self, parent):
    """Constructor"""
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

    rows = [("Ford", "Taurus", "1996", "Blue"),
            ("Nissan", "370Z", "2010", "Green"),
            ("Porche", "911", "2009", "Red")
            ]
    self.list_ctrl = EditableListCtrl(self, style=wx.LC_REPORT)

    self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(0, "Make")
    self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(1, "Model")
    self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(2, "Year")
    self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(3, "Color")

    index = 0
    for row in rows:
        self.list_ctrl.InsertStringItem(index, row[0])
        self.list_ctrl.SetItem(index, 1, row[1])
        self.list_ctrl.SetItem(index, 2, row[2])
        self.list_ctrl.SetItem(index, 3, row[3])
        index += 1
    self.list_ctrl.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_END_LABEL_EDIT, self.OnUpdate)
    sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    sizer.Add(self.list_ctrl, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
    self.SetSizer(sizer)

def OnUpdate(self, event):
    row_id = event.GetIndex() #Get the current row
    col_id = event.GetColumn () #Get the current column
    new_data = event.GetText() #Get the changed data
    print new_data
    cols = self.list_ctrl.GetColumnCount() #Get the total number of columns
    rows = self.list_ctrl.GetItemCount() #Get the total number of rows

    #Get the changed item use the row_id and iterate over the columns
    print (" ".join([self.list_ctrl.GetItem(row_id, colu_id).GetText() for colu_id in range(cols)]))
    print "Changed Item:", new_data, "Column:", col_id

    #Get the entire listctrl iterate over the rows and the columns within each row
    print "\nEntire listctrl BEFORE the update:"
    for row in range(rows):
        row_data = (" ".join([self.list_ctrl.GetItem(row, col).GetText() for col in range(cols)]))
        print row_data

    #Set the new data in the listctrl
    self.list_ctrl.SetItem(row_id,col_id,new_data)

    print "\nEntire listctrl AFTER the update:"
    #Create a list that can be used to export data to a file
    data_for_export=[]
    for row in range(rows):
        row_data = (" ".join([self.list_ctrl.GetItem(row, col).GetText() for col in range(cols)]))
        print row_data
        data_for_export.append(row_data) #Add to the exportable data

    print "\nData for export"
    for row in data_for_export: #Print the data
        print row
```

The bind is as such:

```
self.list_ctrl.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_END_LABEL_EDIT, self.OnUpdate)
```

[image]

As an example, let's say I want to edit 'Blue' into 'Yellow'.

Comment: show small working example. What event do you bind ?

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry. There you go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're close with `event.GetText()`, try `event.GetLabel()` instead and then don't forget to call `event.Skip()`

**Update to reflect OP minimum working code:**

I don't have the code for your `EditableListCtrl` but I've provided a working example with what I assume your code might look like.  To your question about getting the selection, you can get the selected item (which should be the item you're editing) by calling `list_control.GetFirstSelected()` and from that you can call `GetItemText`. Without seeing the `EditableListCtrl` code I would assume your problem stems from an event being caught somewhere else and being vetoed. But that's just a guess.

Here is some minimum working code with what I assume `EditableListCtrl` looks like

```
import wx
from wx.lib.mixins.listctrl import TextEditMixin

class EditableListCtrl(wx.ListCtrl, TextEditMixin):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        wx.ListCtrl.__init__(self, *args, **kw)
        TextEditMixin.__init__(self)


class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, title=wx.EmptyString, pos=wx.DefaultPosition,
                          size=wx.Size(762, 347), style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE | wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)

        self.SetSizeHintsSz(wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize)

        main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.main_panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)
        panel_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.list_ctrl = EditableListCtrl(self.main_panel, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize,
                                     wx.LC_EDIT_LABELS | wx.LC_REPORT) # ---- Changed ------
        panel_sizer.Add(self.list_ctrl, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)

        self.main_panel.SetSizer(panel_sizer)
        self.main_panel.Layout()
        panel_sizer.Fit(self.main_panel)
        main_sizer.Add(self.main_panel, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5)

        self.SetSizer(main_sizer)
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre(wx.BOTH)

        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(0, "Make")
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(1, "Model")
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(2, "Year")
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(3, "Color")

        rows = [("Ford", "Taurus", "1996", "Blue"),
                ("Nissan", "370Z", "2010", "Green"),
                ("Porche", "911", "2009", "Red")
                ]
        index = 0
        for row in rows:
            self.list_ctrl.InsertStringItem(index, row[0])
            self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(index, 1, row[1]) # ---- Changed ------
            self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(index, 2, row[2]) # ---- Changed ------
            self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(index, 3, row[3]) # ---- Changed ------
            index += 1
        self.list_ctrl.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_END_LABEL_EDIT, self.OnUpdate)




    def OnUpdate(self, event):
        self.list_ctrl.Select(event.Item.Id) # force the list to select the event item
        row_id = event.GetIndex() #Get the current row
        col_id = event.GetColumn () #Get the current column
        if col_id < 0: # ---- Changed ------
            col_id = 0 # ---- Changed ------
        new_data = event.GetText() #Get the changed data
        print new_data
        cols = self.list_ctrl.GetColumnCount() #Get the total number of columns
        rows = self.list_ctrl.GetItemCount() #Get the total number of rows


        #Get the changed item use the row_id and iterate over the columns
        print (" ".join([self.list_ctrl.GetItem(row_id, colu_id).GetText() for colu_id in range(cols)]))
        print "Changed Item:", new_data, "Column:", col_id

        #Get the entire listctrl iterate over the rows and the columns within each row
        print "\nEntire listctrl BEFORE the update:"
        for row in range(rows):
            row_data = (" ".join([self.list_ctrl.GetItem(row, col).GetText() for col in range(cols)]))
            print row_data

        #Set the new data in the listctrl
        self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(row_id,col_id,new_data)

        print "\nEntire listctrl AFTER the update:"
        #Create a list that can be used to export data to a file
        data_for_export=[]
        for row in range(rows):
            row_data = (" ".join([self.list_ctrl.GetItem(row, col).GetText() for col in range(cols)]))
            print row_data
            data_for_export.append(row_data) #Add to the exportable data

        print "\nData for export"
        for row in data_for_export: #Print the data
            print row

try:
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MainFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
except Exception:
    from traceback import format_exc
    print(format_exc())
    raw_input("")
```

**Edit #2**
due to some variations between wx installations a different solution was implemented. Changed `OnUpdate` method and added `after_edit_event` method

```
def OnUpdate(self, event):
    event.Skip()
    wx.CallAfter(self.after_edit_event)

def after_edit_event(self):
    rows = self.list_ctrl.GetItemCount()
    cols = self.list_ctrl.GetColumnCount()

    for row in range(rows):
        print(", ".join([self.list_ctrl.GetItem(row, col).GetText() for col in range(cols)]))
```

Comment: It doesn't work. When I do it and attempt to print `new_data`, it does not print anything. :/

Comment: hard to tell without seeing all of the code. Alternatively you could get the selection and then get the item text.

Comment: Code applied, please take a look. :) And what do you mean with selection? (Sorry, I'm relatively new to wxPython)

Comment: I attempted `new_data = self.list_ctrl.GetFirstSelected().GetItemText` but it returned `'long' object has no attribute 'GetItemText'`

Comment: try self.list_ctrl.GetItemText(self.list_ctrl.GetFirstSelected()), sometimes the selection won't change until after the event so you'll have to use wx.CallAfter to call your function after the event has finished

Comment: If I do this, I run into an encoding problem: `SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file C:/...  on line ... , but no encoding declared`

Comment: if you add this at the top of the file do you still get it # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

Comment: That fixes it, however a new problem arises. It says "Couldn't retrieve information about list control item -1".

Comment: that means nothing is selected

Comment: The image I added above shows the GUI. What I do is double-click on 'Blue' and change its value. I want to export the changed cell's new data. Something SHOULD be selected when I do so.

Comment: are you calling wx.CallAfter, you can also do self.list_ctrl.HitTest(event.GetPosition()) which returns the item and flags

Comment: Where do I place the call on wx.CallAfter?

Comment: in OnUpdate, make another method and move the code from OnUpdate to that .... I'll update my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127916/discussion-between-user2682863-and-javanewbie).